# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre poner llaves o no en este bucle?

Tags: java, while

Estaba tratando de utilizar este bucle `while` con un `if` dentro, pero me empezó a surgir un error al momento de compilar por escribirlo así:

```
  while(i<n){

         if(n%i == 0){

         result = false;
         i++;
         }  
   }
```

Luego lo modifique sin las llaves del `if` y el error desapareció.

Me gustaría saber por qué las llaves afectaron al programa.

Solucionado:

```
while(i<n){

     if(n%i == 0)

     result = false;
     i++;
```

}

Comment: Hola. podrias aclarar que error te aparecia.. y tambien.. si sacas esas llaves.. el codigo es totalmente diferente...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sin las llaves:**

```
while( i < n ) {
  if( n % i == 0 )
    result = false;
    i++;
}
```

**Es lo mismo que:**

```
while( i < n ) {
  if( n % i == 0 ) {
    result = false;
  }
    i++;
}
```

**Por tanto si el contador `i` esta dentro del condicional:**

```
while( i < n ) {
  if( n % i == 0 ) {
    result = false;
    i++;//Cuando no se cumpla, i no incrementará y se origina un bucle infinito.
  }
}
```

Es un ejemplo excelente para aprender a hacer Debugging, intenta poner un 'breakpoint' justo en el `while` y ejecuta linea a linea este código. Veras que todo te será mas evidente.

Answer (score 0):

El primero te marca error porque se forma un bucle con un final indefinido, esto ocurre por que tu contador, que permite al bucle continuar, no se encuentra dentro de una condicion que no se cumplicar pues el que su cumpla depende de que aquel contado aumente. Cuando colocas un setencia if que carece de corchetes, la setencia actuara clasificando a la primera linea de codigo siguiente a ella como las setencias que un if llevaria, si la condicon se cumpliera esa setencia seria ejecutada, pero en el caso contrario dicha sentencia seria ignorada y se pasaria a la siguiente.